# Django_permissions, how to template my menu item based on the permissions? in the view.py

Tags: python, django

I want to display menu item based on my given permissions, for example users who are not a Project manager thex dont see item project in the menu and so on..
I have a separated Client dashboard from admin dashboard which is not so good and pro.

Here my code:

## models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model): 
    birthday= models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    address= models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    auth_user = models.ForeignKey(to=User)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Customer'
        permissions = (("view_user", "Can_view_user"),)
```

## views.py

```
class UsersListView(PermissionRequiredMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    login_url = 'accounts/login/'
    permission_required = 'can_view_user'
    template_name = "user_list.html"
    model = User

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if check_permission_BM_or_AM(request):
            if request.user.is_authenticated():
                return super(UsersListView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return redirect_to_login(self.request.get_full_path(),
                             self.get_login_url(),
                             self.get_redirect_field_name())
```

## permission.py

```
def check_permission_BM_or_AM(request):
    customer= Customer.objects.get(auth_user_id=request.user.id)
    marolle = MaRolle.objects.filter(ma=customer.id)
    rollen = Rollen.objects.get(id=1)
    rollens = Rollen.objects.get(id=4)
    for ma in marolle:
        if str(ma.rolle) == rollen.rolle or str(ma.rolle) == rollens.rolle:
            return True
```

## menuitem.html

```
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu ">
        {% if perms.user %}
            <a tabindex="-1" href="/user/list/"><span
                    class="fa fa-fw fa-book "></span> Users</a>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
</ul>
```

how to use the template to get my class view to work based on the given `permission_required = 'can_view_user' permission?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: If i get you, you need to show the same template to every user but a specific item in the menu should be shown only to the one that got permissions right ?

Comment: @jsanchezs exaclty!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before starting, If you are using Django REST your response from the view will be of the form application/json in normal case. [This](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#templatehtmlrenderer) will help you in passing `permission_required = 'can_view_user' in this case.

However, will try to provide a general idea how permission-based functionality can be implemented using Django. Let the three functionality available in dashboard be menu_1, menu_2, and menu_3. Your template can be of the form

```
{% if can_view_menu1 %} 
    Menu option 1
{% endif %} 
{% if can_view_menu2 %}
    Menu option 2
{% endif %} 
{% if can_view_menu3 %}
    Menu option 3
{% endif %}
```

In your view class you can check for the role of the logged-in user and provide the permissions. An example can be as follows.

```
class YourViewClass(ListView):
    # By default noone is permitted to access the view.
    can_view_menu_1 = False
    can_view_menu_2 = False
    can_view_menu_3 = False

    def dispatch(self, reuest, *args, **kwargs):
        if check_permission_RM(request): # returns True if user is RM
            self.can_view_menu_1 = True
        if check_permission_AM_or_PM(request): # returns True if logged in user is AM or PM.
            self.can_view_menu_1 = True
            self.can_view_menu_2 = True
            self.can_view_menu_3 = True
            return super(UsersListView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Remember to pass these variables as context or use DRF templatehtmlrenderer.

Comment: I tried but it doesnt display anymore the menu item at all. here what i did: '{% if can_view_user %}
            <a tabindex="-1" href="/user/list/"><span
                    class="fa fa-fw fa-book "></span> Users</a>
        {% endif %}'

Comment: Are you updating the privileges/ permissions in the view of redirecrt url?

Comment: yes!!  do you meant about the new check method: 
`def check_permission_AM(request):
    customer= Customer.objects.get(auth_user_id=request.user.id)
    marolle = MaRolle.objects.filter(ma=customer.id)
    rollen = Rollen.objects.get(id=4)
    for ma in marolle:
        if str(ma.rolle) == rollen.rolle:
            return True`

Comment: @Dhekra Since you are redirecting the user to a new url after login. There must be a view corresponding to this url, in this view you can pass the context 'can_view_user'. Can you share the view corresponding the url to which you are redirecting?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520656/how-to-edit-the-template-based-on-a-given-role)

Comment: Override get_context_data of your View class [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview).