# Django_permissions, how to template my menu item based on the permissions?

Tags: python, django

I want to display menu item based on my given permissions, for example users who are not a Project manager they cannot have access to the same header of other users with different roles. 
I have implemented Client dashboard and admin dashboard  to separate the users from the templating.

Here my code:

## views.py

```
class UsersListView(istView):
permission_required = 'can_view_user'
template_name = "user_list.html"
model = User

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if check_permission_BM_or_AM(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return super(UsersListView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return redirect_to_login(self.request.get_full_path(),
                         self.get_login_url(),
                         self.get_redirect_field_name())
```

## menuitem.html

```
<ul>
<li class="dropdown-submenu ">
    {% if can_view_user%}
        <a tabindex="-1" href="/user/list/"><span
                class="fa fa-fw fa-book "></span> Users</a>
    {% endif %}
</li>
```

how to use the template to get my class view to work based on the given `permission_required = 'can_view_user' permission?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Override get_context_data method of your UsersListView, Sample can be of the form given below.

```
class UsersListView(ListView):
    # define your variables

    # dispatch method

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['can_view_user'] = self.can_view_user
        return context
```

Comment: it works only when i click the item and the it redirected me to the page and then it is hidden but i wanted just after i login? do you have any idea how could I do it? `@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/administrator/')
    elif request.user.is_active and request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/')`
Thank you

Comment: Then add it to the view of page to which you are navigating, after user login. Say dashboard for example.

Comment: it did not work unfortunately, thnks for your help @Njan